# The whey of ricotta

Tags: cheese, whey

I have made ricotta. (hot milk and lemon)

I have seen some recommendations in relation to the whey of other cheeses. But I am not sure If I can apply it here.

Can you recommend a good use of the whey after making ricotta?

Comment: Nitpick, just because it's a pet peeve of mine: You didn't make ricotta. You made an entirely different cheese which can work as an okay substitute for ricotta in some applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no different than the recommendation for other cheeses.  I've seen suggestions to add to soup, or use in place of water during bread making.